# Bash remove anything OUTSIDE quotation marks

Tags: html, regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a curl request, which returns following output:

```
<a href="spike10-st-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn">pike10-st-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn</a>                 25-Sep-2018 13:49                4947
<a href="spike11-First-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn">spike11-First-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn</a>                 25-Sep-2018 14:04                4951
<a href="spike12-rst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn">spike12-rst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn</a>                 25-Sep-2018 14:27                4947
<a href="spike13-irst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn">spike13-irst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn</a>                 25-Sep-2018 15:00                4947
```

Can anyone give me a hint, how to remove all outside quotation marks to receive only names of *.ovpn files, like this:

```
spike10-st-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn
spike11-First-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn
spike12-rst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn
spike13-irst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn
```

Comment: Use an HTML parser like `xmllint` or `xmlstarlet` to extract the value of the `href` attribute of each `a` element.

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858)

Comment: You ask for the href fields, not the description. Your example is slightly confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the input won't contain any extra quotation marks, you can just use `cut`

```
cut -d\" -f2 filename
```

This will delimit on quotation marks, and get the 2nd field. Simple.

Answer (score 4):

Get value of attribute `href` with a valid HTML file:

```
xmlstarlet select --text --template --value-of '//a/@href' -n file.html
```

Output:

```
pike10-st-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn
spike11-First-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn
spike12-rst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn
spike13-irst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn
```

---

See: `xmlstarlet select --help`

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: Thanks for the question, but unfortunately I can't accommodate that in time.  Yes, the documentation could be much better.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 while I agree that xmlstarlet's documentation is rather sparse, I do believe that 90% of its complexity and misunderstanding comes from XPath which is far from logical. If you understand the latter, it becomes much more interesting. But to my opinion, mastering Xpath comes close to trying to boil an ocean!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to remove anything outside quotation marks:

```
awk -F\" '{print $2}' file

spike10-st-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn
spike11-First-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn
spike12-rst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn
spike13-irst-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn
```

Comment: Please explain what your code is trying to do, not just lines of code.

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono nonsense. Explaining that code would be as useful as adding an `incrementing i` comment to `i++`.

Comment: @EdMorton feel free to disagree. I understand what the code does, but I'm also following SO guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
To me, adding the remark on what the code does will be helpful for others, especially newbie.

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono, while you're not wrong, the code in this answer is so blatantly obvious that I'd expect anyone who included an [tag:awk] tag in their question to be able to read and understand it. The code in this answer is *infinitely* longer and more complex than the awk code in the question .. which is a criticism of the question (which should perhaps be closed) rather than of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following(considering that your actual Input_file is same as show samples).

```
awk 'match($0,/href="[^"]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

this regular expression help you to remove unwanted string.

```
.replace(/(.*)(["])(.*)(["])(.*)/g, '$3')


'<a href="spike10-st-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn">pike10-st-d43d7eff66aa.ovpn</a>                 25-Sep-2018 13:49                4947'.replace(/(.*)(["])(.*)(["])(.*)/g, '$3')
```